# How can I express these three button functions in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#addButton1").on("click", function(){
    let addMenu = new Menu(allMenu[0].Id, allMenu[0].Title);
    console.log(`newOrder : ${addMenu.mId}`);
    addToCart(addMenu);
});

$("#addButton2").on("click", function(){
    let addMenu = new Menu(allMenu[1].Id, allMenu[1].Title);
    console.log(`newOrder : ${addMenu.mId}`);
    addToCart(addMenu);
});
$("#addButton3").on("click", function(){
    let addMenu = new Menu(allMenu[2].Id, allMenu[2].Title);
    console.log(`newOrder : ${addMenu.mId}`);
    addToCart(addMenu);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72598425/edit) your question and try to make it clearer what answer you are looking for. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

looks like

```
for(let i=0;i<allMenu.length;i++){
   $(`#addButton${i+1}`).on("click", function(){
    let addMenu = new Menu(allMenu[i].Id, allMenu[i].Title);
    console.log(`newOrder : ${addMenu.mId}`);
    addToCart(addMenu);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An excellent way to perform this action is by using class and data

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
    Product 1
    <span class="addToCart" data-product="1">Add to Cart</span>
</div>
<div>
    Product 1
    <span class="addToCart" data-product="2">Add to Cart</span>
</div>
<div>
    Product 3
    <span class="addToCart" data-product="3">Add to Cart</span>
</div>
<div>
    Product 4
    <span class="addToCart" data-product="4">Add to Cart</span>
</div>
```

**add.js**

```
$(".addToCart").on("click", function(){
    let product = $(this).data("product")
    let addMenu = new Menu(allMenu[product].Id, allMenu[product].Title);
    console.log(`newOrder : ${addMenu.mId}`);
    addToCart(addMenu);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use prefix selector to selecting the similar elements,for example,
selects those whose id starts with addButton,

> addButton1,addButton2,addButtonme selects all of them because they all start with addButton

```js
$('div[id^="addButton"]').
```

Comment: Or, just not use semantic IDs.  Much simpler.

Comment: maybe attributes are generated dynamically sometimes